# CUDADot[] takes ~3x time compared to Dot[]

Tags: performance-tuning, cuda

It all started when specifying TargetDevice -> "GPU" in `Classify[]` yielded no speedup nor any activity in the GPU. Then I tried something simpler like `CUDADot[]`, just to see that it is ~3x time **slower** than plain `Dot[]`:

```
<< CUDALink`
M = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5000, 5000}];

AbsoluteTiming[Dot[M, M];]
(* {2.72066, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[CUDADot[M, M];]
(* {8.20455, Null} *)
```

EDIT: Even after using `CUDAMemoryLoad[]`, it still is slower:

```
<< CUDALink`
M = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5000, 5000}];

AbsoluteTiming[Dot[M, M];]
(* {2.29508, Null} *)

CM = CUDAMemoryLoad[M];
AbsoluteTiming[CUDADot[CM, CM];]
(* {7.47153, Null} *)
CUDAMemoryUnload[CM];
```

After all, perhaps the h/w is to blame, as the same slowdown in Matlab is also seen:

```
>> x = gpuArray([1:0.3:10000]);
>> tic; dot(x,x); toc
Elapsed time is 0.316340 seconds.
>> 
>> x = [1:0.3:10000];
>> tic; dot(x,x); toc
Elapsed time is 0.014257 seconds.
>>
```

But the workaround (forcing the usage of low-precision floating point arithmetic, i.e. 32 rather than 64 bits) doesn't seem to make things right:

```
<< CUDALink`
M = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5000, 5000}];

AbsoluteTiming[Dot[M, M];]
(* {2.77907, Null} *)

CM = CUDAMemoryLoad[M, "Float"];
AbsoluteTiming[CUDADot[CM, CM];]
(* {8.0693, Null} *)
CUDAMemoryUnload[CM];
```

My environment, I think, is setup fine:

```
CUDAQ[]
(* True *)

CUDAInformation[]
(* {1 -> {"Name" -> "GeForce MX150", "Clock Rate" -> 1037500, 
"Compute Capabilities" -> 6.1, "GPU Overlap" -> 1, 
"Maximum Block Dimensions" -> {1024, 1024, 64}, 
"Maximum Grid Dimensions" -> {2147483647, 65535, 65535}, 
"Maximum Threads Per Block" -> 1024, 
"Maximum Shared Memory Per Block" -> 49152, 
"Total Constant Memory" -> 65536, "Warp Size" -> 32, 
"Maximum Pitch" -> 2147483647, 
"Maximum Registers Per Block" -> 65536, "Texture Alignment" -> 512,
"Multiprocessor Count" -> 3, "Core Count" -> 96, 
"Execution Timeout" -> 1, "Integrated" -> False, 
"Can Map Host Memory" -> True, "Compute Mode" -> "Default", 
"Texture1D Width" -> 131072, "Texture2D Width" -> 131072, 
"Texture2D Height" -> 65536, "Texture3D Width" -> 16384, 
"Texture3D Height" -> 16384, "Texture3D Depth" -> 16384, 
"Texture2D Array Width" -> 32768, 
"Texture2D Array Height" -> 32768, 
"Texture2D Array Slices" -> 2048, "Surface Alignment" -> 512, 
"Concurrent Kernels" -> True, "ECC Enabled" -> False, 
"TCC Enabled" -> False, "Total Memory" -> 2147483648}} *)

CUDADriverVersion[]
(* "430.86" *)

$Version
(* 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018) *)
```

Any ideas folks? I'd really like to avoid using Matlab ^^. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just curious: does Matlab (which you mention) perform better on the CPU and on the GPU?

Comment: `CUDADot` documentation mentions `CUDAMemory` objects, which I would assume to be significantly more efficient to use (data being stored on GPU memory, but also requires explicit memory management). Have you tried to `CUDAMemoryLoad` your data, and to time `CUDADot` on these objects only after loading them?

Comment: Actually, this is probably a result of FP64 (64-bit IEEE floating point, the machine precision preferred by Mathematica) arithmetic being quite slow on MX150. Apparently it can perform FP64 at about 35 GFLOPs, while 32-bit floating point (FP32) performs at 1127 GFLOPs. (This is not uncommon on non-compute oriented consumer GPUs.) 35 GFLOPs is well below theoretical performance of a modern AVX2-enabled quad-core CPU. You may be able to speed up your computation by forcing usage of lower-precision `"Float"` type data, which should correspond with FP32.

Comment: Thanks folks for taking time to comment. How do I force usage of "Float" type data in Mathematica?

Comment: CUDALink tutorial suggests that you could use `CUDAMemoryLoad[data, "Float"]`. (Note that you have to explicitly free such memory using `CUDAMemoryUnload` to avoid memory leaks.) I don't have a NVIDIA system to try this out at the moment. I speculate that `NumericArray[data, "Real32"]` could work also for your original `CUDADot` example, but I have no way to test this.

Comment: Curious that `"Float"` type doesn't help! I'm out of ideas. :o

Comment: I wonder whether my license being "Student" has anything to do with it (long shot). Anyway, I wrote to support. Thanks everyone for your time!

Comment: Towards usage of CUDA and OpenCL in _Mathematica_, I'd suggest to not use them together. The CUDA interface was implemented very half-heartedly many years ago (you may legtimately ask "What interface?"), was strongly marketed and hyped for one or two minor releases, and not maintained since then. (The situation for OpenCL is even worse: Almost nothing usable is implemented and most documentation consists of statements like "It's all similar to CUDA.")

Comment: The problem with GPU programming is that you have to do almost all computations on the GPU, because communication between GPU and CPU is ridiculously expensive. Thus, in order to profit from GPU programming, you need quite a vast library of operations implemented for GPU. _Mathematica_  and  _CUDALink_ clearly lack this backbone. IMHO, this renders _CUDALink_ quite useless for the practitioner.

Comment: In total, that's not too unfortunate: _Mathematica's_ greatest strength is very fast prototyping; GPU programming is pretty at the _(other)_ end of the development pipeline. So, although it would be great to do so, it is not absolutely necessary to bring them together.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The whole thing started when `Classify[]` couldn't use the GPU. And GPU in modern classification problems is IMHO necessary even for "prototyping".

Comment: @Zet, what is the defined count of CUDA cores in your GPU? What happens when you try to use one with more, such as a GTX1*** or RTX2***?